# Comparisons in C VS VB

Tags: c, vb.net

Here is the C code:

```
do
{
    printf("\nOver eighteen (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c", over18);

    if(over18 != "Y" || over18 != "N")
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input");
    }

}  while(over18 != "Y" && over18 != "N");
```

Hey, I am new to C and I am trying to sort-off translate my old VB code from when I was learning that into C. I have attempted to do that for this part of a program, but that gives the error "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" for all my comparisons using "!=".
Here is the VB code:

```
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Are you over eighteen (Y/N)?")
        over18 = Console.ReadLine()

        If over18 <> "Y" And over18 <> "N" Then
            Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid answer")
        End If

    Loop Until over18 = "Y" Or over18 = "N"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Character in C language - 'Y'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always show all relevant code. At least the definitions of all variables in use should be known. Preferably we should be able to copy&paste your code and compile it.

Answer (score -1):

In C, strings are just arrays of chars, which translates into a char pointer.

So, to compare strings, you must use the function `strcmp`.

Your code should then be the following

```
strcmp(over18, "Y") != 0
```

Comment: As `over18` is used to read a single `char` only, it is not safe to assume proper string termination. From the mentioned compiler warning it seems that it is a single `char`. Therefore comparing with `over18 != 'Y'` would be more suitable